# Delphi and Honeywell Android Mobile Scanner not populating after keyboard use

Tags: android, delphi, barcode, firemonkey, honeywell

I am creating a stock take application in Firemonkey (Delphi Seattle) and have a problem with the built in scanner.

I focus on a TEdit then scan a barcode and it populates the TEdit but as soon as I hit the backspace or enter button on the virtual keyboard and then try scan again, it doesn't populate with the barcode.

I can set focus to another control and try scan again and still it wont populate the control.

I have to close the application then open it again and I can scan again until I use the virtual keyboard and the backspace or enter button.

The built in scanner is set to wedge which emulates keyboard input.

I tested the process in a notepad application for android and that seems to work fine. ie I can do the same process as in Firemonkey but the scanner still populates the notepad with text.

If I add a \n suffix to the scanner then the return key is being recognised but not the actual barcode. The first barcode scans but thereafter only the return key is being recognised.

Something in Firemonkey must be blocking the input.

Does anyone have any ideas on where I can look to try and fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is no real solution to the. I needed to use the SDK provided with the scanner and access the scanner activities. The solution to this can be found here [Embarcadero Forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=205636)